# Fastest way to load html file to php script

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler, domdocument

i've been writing a web crawler on php, i am using the following method:

**Current Method**

```
function getPublicationData($url){
    static $seen = array();
    if (isset($seen[$url])) {
        return;
    }
    $seen[$url] = true;

    $cURL = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $htmlDoc = curl_exec($cURL);

    $dom= new DOMDocument('1.0');
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($htmlDoc);
    $dom_xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $strongElements = $dom_xpath->query("//strong[@class='publication-meta-type']");
    foreach( $strongElements as $strongElement){
        echo $strongElement->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

The problem is that php has a 30 second time limit, and i need to access a quite large number of pages (My host doesnt let me change the time limit).

It would be nice to be able to get only a few specific nodes from the page or something like that.

Can someone give me a solution?

Comment: @Martin I suspect OP is on shared hosting. Hosts that limit PHP's execution time ("My host doesnt let me change the time limit") aren't likely to let you edit php.ini to remove those limits.

Comment: @ceejayoz I just read that and so deleted my comment :-p

Comment: How is this method run? Are you running it from the browser or from some cron script?

Comment: How about regulating your script to keep track of itself as page loads will be in a loop structure you can time the loop and say after 25seconds you can then tell your script to mark where it's got to and then call a reload `header` to reload the page and prevent time out, would that be feesable?

Comment: @moscar This code is from a wordpress plugin.

Comment: @Martin Can you show  me how i could do that?

Answer (score 2):

Make a asynchronous call to your database with html's.

**PART I**

```
static $seen = array();
if (isset($seen[$url])) {
    return;
}
$seen[$url] = true;

$cURL = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$htmlDoc = curl_exec($cURL);
//save in file, database, whatever
```

**PART II**

Create a cron job, or another way to call your function to parse data, and save in your database:

```
$htmlDoc = //get data from whatever you decided to save
$dom= new DOMDocument('1.0');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($htmlDoc);
$dom_xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$strongElements = $dom_xpath->query("//strong[@class='publication-meta-type']");
foreach( $strongElements as $strongElement){
    echo $strongElement->nodeValue;
....
```

Answer (score 1):

The time consuming part is almost certainly the HTTP requests. Not much you can do to speed that up.

Solution? Time to get a new host.